# Como Obtener la ruta del archivo cargado de input type file?

Tags: javascript, html5

Muy  buenas a todos, actualmente he estado intentando obtener el url del archivo que se carga desde el input type file, sin poder lograrlo, cuento con un archivo aparte para el codigo js, como pueden ver por el momento solo puedo obtener el nombre de archivo, cosa que también me sirve pero no he podido devolver la url.

```
<div style="margin-left: 410px;" class="container p-4">
        <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
            <h1>Cargue su archivo</h1>
            <div>
                <input type="file" accept=".pdf, .jpg" multiple="multiple" id="archivo" onchange="getname()"/>        
                <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-stack-2x bottom pulsating"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-1x top medium"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up fa-stack-1x top"></i>
                </span>
                <span class="desc">Pulse aquí para añadir archivos</span>

            <a class="btn btn-danger white">
                Enviar
            </a>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Este es mi app.js

```
function getname(){
    var resultado = document.getElementById('archivo').files[0].name;
    console.log(resultado);
}
```

Comment: Por razones de seguridad no se puede.

Comment: Lo que sucede es que la necesito para poder subir este archivo a un servidor, y considero que necesito saber donde está ubicado en la pc.

Comment: No es por que no podamos decirte el como, es porque javascript como tal no lo permite.

Comment: No es necesario saber la ruta del archivo para enviarlo, con tener el archivo cargado en el input ya puedes enviarlo ya sea mediante ajax o con el formulario mismo.